# Child routes in controller

Tags: routes, nestjs

The problem came to me when I tried to get a comment from the post, I have a separate module for comments and for posts.

***I now have these routes:***

### Comments

- Get /comments
- Get /comments/:id
- Post /comments
- Put /comments/:id
- Delete /comments/:id

### Posts

- Get /posts
- Get /posts/:id
- Post /posts
- Put /posts/:id
- Delete /posts/:id

***I want to get this kind of routes:***

### Posts

- Get /posts
- Get /posts/:id
- Post /posts
- Put /posts/:id
- Delete /posts/:id

### Comments

- Get /posts/:id/comments
- Get /posts/:id/comments/:id
- Post /posts/:id/comments
- Put /posts/:id/comments/:id
- Delete /posts/:id/comments/:id

***How I can solve this using NestJS?***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this nest router package : https://github.com/shekohex/nest-router , they are an issue about this problem https://github.com/shekohex/nest-router/issues/43 . I think this can resolve your problem. 
Using GraphQL can be a good possibilities to resolve some REST problems

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already understood that there is a problem in NestJS.
Since there is no longer any solution other than GraphQL, I will mark your answer as a solution.